# Java write to .pdf with color

Tags: java, pdf, colors

I would like to create a .pdf file and then write to it in color. Through consoles, I have been able to do that with ansi escape sequences. For example if I want red I put `"\u001b[31m"` in front of my string and `"\u001b[0m"` to remove all the formatting. You can change the background and the foreground. I designed my own useful class around this to help with displaying information and even for a text-based chess project I am *still* working on.

However, now I would like to write to files with colors. I would like to do a similar thing that I did with the ansi escapes but probably not with escapes.

If I want to create color in a .pdf, how would I do that (**without utilizing an external source**)? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: *without using an import* - what do you mean by that?

Comment: @mkl Without downloading an outside project... I changed it; sorry that was wonky of me to say. I don't want to have to download unless it's just to take a look at.

Comment: Creating PDFs is quite complicated, at least if you want to support many PDF features in an intuitive manner. It's there a specific reason why you don't want external libraries?

Comment: There are numerous open source java PDF libraries (e.g. iText, PDFBox, PDFClown). You might want to take a look at them to get an impression what is necessary for a serious PDF library.

Comment: @mkl All I want is to be able to write text with background and foreground color, and I want to learn how to do it. I don't want/need other features.

Comment: What kind of text? I.e. would a WinAnsi character set in a very few fonts suffice?

Comment: @mkl Just any plain/default text if that is possible. If not then WinAnsi with few fonts would be fine. I don't know what WinAnsi is, but sure. If I get color, I am :D - I researched WinAnsi a little and I am confused as to what it characterizes. You say it is a character set and that it has multiple fonts. If I use one of the fonts, how would I get color in a pdf (even if I had to - which I won't - write byte by byte)?

Comment: PDF defines some character sets and fonts available on every PDF Reader. If these suffice, a simple PDF creator is feasible. I have no idea, though, what you mean by *plain/default text*.

Comment: @mkl Then infer. All I want is text in a PDF with color, and I don't particularly want to have to have to use an outside resource. As aforementioned, I could not care less what font it is - all I want is text. If you actually know how to do this, then please provide me with a link or explain in an answer. If you are just yanking my chain or if I don't get a valid response that explains how to/where to find how to do this, then I will delete this question.

Comment: I'm not *yanking chains*. I merely want to make sure that I really know what the OP aks for before I invest some time in a serious answer here. And as said before, this is not trivial.

Comment: @mkl Any font with color. I think I am going to give up this project. Thanks for steering me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a quick hack of a very very simple PDF creator class which can do nothing more than writing Courier text in color on colored background:

```
public class SimplePdfCreator
{
    /**
     * Creates a {@link SimplePdfCreator} instance writing to the
     * given {@link OutputStream}.
     */
    public SimplePdfCreator(OutputStream os) throws IOException
    {
        pdfOs = os instanceof BufferedOutputStream ? (BufferedOutputStream) os : new BufferedOutputStream(os);

        writeHeader();
        fontObjectNr = writeFont();
        initPage();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the (fill) color for the upcoming operations on the current page.
     */
    public void color(float r, float g, float b)
    {
        pageBuilder.append(r)
                   .append(' ')
                   .append(g)
                   .append(' ')
                   .append(b)
                   .append(" rg\n");
    }

    /**
     * Sets the background (fill) color for the upcoming operations on the current page.
     */
    public void backColor(float r, float g, float b)
    {
        backBuilder.append(r)
                   .append(' ')
                   .append(g)
                   .append(' ')
                   .append(b)
                   .append(" rg\n");
    }

    /**
     * Prints the given text on a baseline starting at the given coordinates
     * on the current page.
     */
    public void print(int x, int y, String string)
    {
        pageBuilder.append(x - xNow)
                   .append(' ')
                   .append(y - yNow)
                   .append(" Td (")
                   .append(string)
                   .append(") Tj\n");
        xNow = x;
        yNow = y;
        fillBack(string);
    }

    /**
     * Prints the given text on the next line on the current page.
     */
    public void print(String string)
    {
        pageBuilder.append("(")
                   .append(string)
                   .append(") '\n");
        yNow -= leading;
        fillBack(string);
    }

    /**
     * Stores the current page with the printed content in the output
     * and creates a new one.
     */
    public void storePage() throws IOException
    {
        writePageContent();
        initPage();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the width of the given String.
     */
    public double getStringWidth(String string)
    {
        return string.length() * fontSize * .6;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the font size
     */
    public int getFontSize()
    {
        return fontSize;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the leading
     */
    public int getLeading()
    {
        return leading;
    }

    /**
     * Finishes the output writing required data to it and closing the
     * target {@link OutputStream}.
     */
    public void close() throws IOException
    {
        int pagesObjectNr = writePages();
        int catalogObjectNr = writeCatalog(pagesObjectNr);
        long xrefPosition = writeXref();
        writeTrailer(catalogObjectNr);
        writeFooter(xrefPosition);
        pdfOs.close();;
    }

    //
    // helper methods
    //
    void writeHeader() throws IOException
    {
        write("%PDF-1.4\n".getBytes(charSet));
        write(new byte[]{'%', (byte)128, (byte)129, (byte)130, '\n'});
    }

    int writeFont() throws IOException
    {
        return writeObject("<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Courier/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>\n".getBytes(charSet));
    }

    void initPage()
    {
        pageBuilder.setLength(0);
        backBuilder.setLength(0);
        pageBuilder.append("BT/F0 ")
                   .append(fontSize)
                   .append(" Tf ")
                   .append(leading)
                   .append(" TL 0 g\n");
        backBuilder.append("1 g\n");
        xNow = 0;
        yNow = 0;
    }

    void fillBack(String string)
    {
        backBuilder.append(xNow)
                   .append(' ')
                   .append(yNow - leading*.2)
                   .append(' ')
                   .append(getStringWidth(string))
                   .append(' ')
                   .append(leading)
                   .append(" re f\n");
    }

    void writePageContent() throws IOException
    {
        pageBuilder.append("ET\n");
        StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
        contents.append("<</Length ")
                .append(pageBuilder.length() + backBuilder.length())
                .append(">>\nstream\n")
                .append(backBuilder)
                .append(pageBuilder)
                .append("\nendstream\n");
        int contentsObjectNr = writeObject(contents.toString().getBytes(charSet));
        pageContentsObjects.add(contentsObjectNr);
    }

    int writePages() throws IOException
    {
        int pagesObjectNrToBe = xref.size() + pageContentsObjects.size() + 1;
        StringBuilder pages = new StringBuilder();
        pages.append("<</Type /Pages /Count ")
             .append(pageContentsObjects.size())
             .append("/Kids[");
        for (int pageContentObject : pageContentsObjects)
        {
            int pageObjectNr = writeObject(String.format("<</Type/Page/Parent %s 0 R/Contents %s 0 R>>\n", pagesObjectNrToBe, pageContentObject).getBytes(charSet));
            pages.append(pageObjectNr).append(" 0 R ");
        }
        pages.append("]/Resources<</ProcSet[/PDF/Text]/Font<</F0 ")
             .append(fontObjectNr)
             .append(" 0 R>>>>/MediaBox[0 0 612 792]>>\n");
        return writeObject(pages.toString().getBytes(charSet));
    }

    int writeCatalog(int pagesObjectNr) throws IOException
    {
        return writeObject(String.format("<</Type/Catalog/Pages %s 0 R>>\n", pagesObjectNr).getBytes(charSet));
    }

    long writeXref() throws IOException
    {
        long xrefPos = position;
        byte[] eol = new byte[]{'\n'};
        write("xref\n".getBytes(charSet));
        write(String.format("0 %s\n", xref.size() + 1).getBytes(charSet));
        write("0000000000 65535 f ".getBytes(charSet));
        write(eol);
        for(long position: xref)
        {
            write(String.format("%010d 00000 n ", position).getBytes(charSet));
            write(eol);
        }
        return xrefPos;
    }

    void writeTrailer(int catalogObjectNr) throws IOException
    {
        write(String.format("trailer\n<</Size %s/Root %s 0 R>>\n", xref.size() + 1, catalogObjectNr).getBytes(charSet));
    }

    void writeFooter(long xrefPosition) throws IOException
    {
        write(String.format("startxref\n%s\n%%%%EOF\n", xrefPosition).getBytes(charSet));
    }

    int writeObject(byte[] bytes) throws IOException
    {
        int objectNr = startObject();
        write(bytes);
        endObj();
        return objectNr;
    }

    int startObject() throws IOException
    {
        xref.add(position);
        int objectNr = xref.size();
        write(String.format("%s 0 obj\n", objectNr).getBytes(charSet));
        return objectNr;
    }

    void endObj() throws IOException
    {
        write("endobj\n".getBytes(charSet));
    }

    long write(byte[] bytes) throws IOException
    {
        if (bytes != null)
        {
            pdfOs.write(bytes);
            position += bytes.length;
        }
        return position;
    }

    final BufferedOutputStream pdfOs;
    final Charset charSet = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
    final List<Long> xref = new ArrayList<Long>();
    final List<Integer> pageContentsObjects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    final StringBuilder pageBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    final StringBuilder backBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    final int fontObjectNr;
    long position = 0;

    int xNow = 0;
    int yNow = 0;

    int fontSize = 11;
    int leading = 11;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
public void test() throws IOException
{
    SimplePdfCreator creator = new SimplePdfCreator(new FileOutputStream("target/test-outputs/SimpleGenerated.pdf"));

    creator.print(100, 500, "Test line 1");
    creator.print("Test line 2");

    creator.color(1, 0, 0);
    creator.backColor(0, 1, 1);
    creator.print(100, 450, "Test line red");
    creator.color(0, 1, 0);
    creator.backColor(1, 0, 1);
    creator.print("Test line green");
    creator.color(0, 0, 1);
    creator.backColor(1, 1, 0);
    creator.print("Test line blue");

    creator.color(1, 1, 1);
    creator.backColor(0, 0, 0);

    creator.print(100, 400, "step");
    creator.print(100 + (int)creator.getStringWidth("step"), 400 - creator.getLeading(), "by");
    creator.print(100 + (int)creator.getStringWidth("stepby"), 400 - 2 * creator.getLeading(), "step");

    creator.storePage();

    creator.print(100, 400, "Page 2");

    creator.storePage();

    creator.close();
}
```

Which creates this:

[image]

And remember, as mentioned above, this is a quick hack, maybe a prove of concept, and there is much to improve, e.g. coordinates probably should be double instead of int, strings shall be escaped before adding to the content (especially concerning brackets, ...