# PostScript PDF (1.7), manually writing code

Tags: pdf, text, postscript

I'm trying to manually write a simple **PDF** file that contains a **title, some text**, and an image. I found one example of a manually written *"Hello world"* and managed to change some things, but I cant get it working for another text object. I have looked for help on the internet but with no luck, I guess not many people write their own PDF files.

This is what I have so far:

```
%PDF-1.7



1 0 obj  % entry point
<<
  /Type /Catalog
  /Pages 2 0 R
>>
endobj



2 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Pages
  /MediaBox [ 0 0 200 200 ]
  /Count 1
  /Kids [ 3 0 R ]
>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Page
  /Parent 2 0 R
  /Resources <<
    /Font <<
      /F1 4 0 R 
    >>
  >>
  /Contents 4 0 R
>>
endobj


4 0 obj  % page content
<<
  /Length 20
>>
stream
BT
80 180 TD
/F1 14 Tf
(PDF) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj

5 0 obj  % page content
<<
  /Length 20
>>
stream
BT
50 70 TD
/F1 14 Tf
(this is a pdf) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj


trailer
<<
  /Size 6
  /Root 1 0 R
>>
startxref
492
%%EOF
```

I have tried adding another text object with "this is a pdf" text but it wont show up, I don't know what could be wrong, I tried changing a few things but with no luck. The image part I don't have it either, so some help with that would be nice.

This is a wiki about the "hello world" pdf I found:
http://www.gnupdf.org/Introduction_to_PDF

Adobe offers some explanation on how the pdf works but I cant find anything that would fix my problem:
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf

Comment: I don't know if it'll explain the whole problem, but you have a `startxref` entry but no `xref` table in your file.

Comment: Yes it seems like it, but it works if you copy and save it as a pdf.

Comment: 'works' how ? You mean it opens in Acrobat probably. Acrobat opens all kinds of broken PDF files and silently repairs them. If Acrobat offers to 'save changes' when you exit, and you didn't change the PDF, then that's a good indication your original file is broken. Lucas is quite correct, you have no xref and so your PDF file is not valid.

Comment: You've also declared a font 'F1' as being object 4 0, which is the content stream for your page, and not a valid font. Your comment says that object 5 0 is the 'page content' which doesn't seem to be true, and object 5 doesn't seem to be referenced anywhere.

Comment: For a simple Java sample, have a look [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25244100/1729265).

Comment: So from what I understand I need to keep referencing the objects being added, how should I go about doing this if I need an xref table that points to the exact position of the objects?

Comment: *how should I go about doing this if I need an xref table that points to the exact position of the objects* - count the bytes. If you seriously want to create PDFs manually, what else could you do?

Comment: You could experiment with [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html), which can convert to and from an actual PDF and an easier editable intermediate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a valid PDF. If Acrobat opens it at all it's because it's given up on the xref table and done a full scan of the file, but your PDF is invalid. 4 0 obj is not a font, as you specified, and 5 0 obj is not accessed from anywhere.

PDF specification requires an xref table which points to the exact position in the file for each object. You can't realistically write this by hand unless you intend to manually update the entire xref table every time you add or remove even 1 byte from the file.

You can write a PDF from scratch like this from code easily enough but it will not work to just open a PDF in notepad and start changing things because the index (xref) immediately becomes corrupt.

I'd also advise against putting comments throughout the file unless the comments start on new lines. Otherwise some PDF parsers will get confused as this is generally not expected. Usually PDF files do not contain comments (with the exception of the second line, which is recommended by Adobe to be a comment of some non-ASCII characters so FTP recognizes the file as binary) seeing as they are virtually impossible to write manually anyway.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html

Comment: Concerning the warning concerning the use of comments... Comments are a simple standard PDF construct. PDF viewers not supporting them can be considered as broken as the PDF of the OP.

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago, I wrote a book which covers exactly this sort of thing:

[http://www.amazon.com/PDF-Explained-John-Whitington/dp/1449310028/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449310028)

No free online version, I'm afraid. You can get all the same information from Adobe's own documentation, which is free, but it's a rather long document!