# How would I make an pdf without using an php library?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I've been looking for creating a pdf using php without using a library but when I was looking on google for this I am not being able find any information how a pdf is made within php. Now I know the simple answer is 'Look at the code of an existing library'. But this does not give me much detail and how/why certain lines of codes are being used and what is or what isn't bad practice.

I hope, any of you have some prior experience with this and can help me out.

Comment: Well you could throw a PDF header pretty easily.. what do you require? Why not just use the existing libraries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to create a PDF Writer like iTextSharp not use iTextSharp - Creating PDFs from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041830/i-want-to-create-a-pdf-writer-like-itextsharp-not-use-itextsharp-creating-pdfs)

Comment: You can create a PDF document without libraries, but you will only be able to do this for very trivial PDF files.  Very quickly you will see that PDF is complicated which is why you need a library.